# Unable to connect to Oracle DB by Tableau from windows10

Tags: oracle, driver, tableau-api

I have installed tableau desktop version 2020.1.3 (with its license) and also its required drivers from [here](https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers?_ga=2.86484056.1520735821.1593928570-563081219.1592281334&_fsi=zs9qi5oF).

Now, according to what is considered in installation guides, what I am supposed to do as first step, would be just to open the tableau software and enter the needed connection information to connect to Oracle DB.
Although I done these steps in the said way, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while communicating with the data source
Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
Error Code: 37CE01A3
No details available.
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Are there any settings or configurations that I did not attention to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the related log file, I have found that the wrong is with Java version. So, I installed a higher version of Java, and everything went well. To me, available Java version was 1.7 that I change it to 1.8.